# Change loop to write results in additional cells

Tags: worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

I have been using the following code for awhile but need some help in making one change. I’ve tried and tried but it won’t work. If someone could kindly take a look, my research says I’m looking for a “change loop to write results to additional cells”.  Please see my Excel image below.

Right now the code finds all matching number(s) entered in the A1 cell and posts them in the appropriate cells L1:l12. I need the code to also post the same information in only one of the following cells: C17, C18, F17, F18. Also, if the code could copy and paste the number in the cell below the matching number (from cell A1), see sample result below) into the cell to the left of the above change loop paste in the following cells: B17, B18, E17, E18.

Example with expected result as per the sample Excel image. Number 8 was entered in cell A1 and found 8 in cell A34. So 8-15 would be copied and pasted to L8 and C17. It would also copy the number 7 from cell A35 (the following number) to cell B17. The code would also do the same for cell F20 and E21. After all the coping and pasting all the cells B34, C34 and D34 need to be deleted and so would be blank. Same for F20, G20 and H20. I hope this is clear, if not please advise and I will clarify.

My working code is below and my attempt is below that code.

[image: Excel sheet]

Working code:

```
Sub do_it()

    Dim n, sht As Worksheet, cell As Range, num, tmp, rngDest As Range

    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    n = sht.Range("A1")

    For Each cell In sht.Range("A20:A34,D20:D34,G20:G34").Cells

        tmp = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value

        If cell.Value = n And tmp Like "*#-#*" Then

            'get the first number
            num = CLng(Trim(Split(tmp, "-")(0)))
            Debug.Print "Found a positive result in " & cell.Address
 'find the next empty cell in the appropriate row
         Set rngDest = sht.Cells(num, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)
            'make sure not to add before col L
            If rngDest.Column < 12 Then Set rngDest = sht.Cells(num, 12)

            cell.Offset(0, 1).Copy rngDest

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

My attempt:

```
Sub do_it()

    Dim n, sht As Worksheet, cell As Range, num, tmp, rngDest As Range

    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    n = sht.Range("A1")

    For Each cell In sht.Range("A20:A34,D20:D34,G20:G34").Cells

        tmp = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value

        If cell.Value = n And tmp Like "*#-#*" Then

            'get the first number
            num = CLng(Trim(Split(tmp, "-")(0)))
            Debug.Print "Found a positive result in " & cell.Address
 'find the next empty cell in the appropriate row
         Set rngDest = (“ C17, C18, F17, F18’)
             cell.Offset(0, 1).Copy rngDest

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It might not be pretty or scalable, but since I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve in the long run, here is something that should work.

First of, the row `For Each cell In sht.Range("A20:A34,D20:D34,G20:G34").Cells` does not correspond with the cells used in your example, so I changed that to:

```
For Each cell In sht.Range("A20:A34,E20:E34,I20:I34").Cells
```

Then I Hijacked the tmp variable at the end, because it's not used anymore, and set it to find the last cell of the column where it found a match, like so:

```
Set tmp = sht.Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, cell.Column).End(xlUp).Row, cell.Column)
```

Then we need to specify the new boxes, and make sure we only fill each once.
You could do this by checking is the first one is empty, or with a counter.
Either way, it will only work properly as long as you find less than 4 matches.

End result was this, modify as needed;

```
Sub do_it()

Dim sht As Worksheet, n As String, cell, num, tmp, rngDest As Range, i As Integer
Set sht = ActiveSheet
n = sht.Range("A1").Value
i = 0
For Each cell In sht.Range("A20:A34,E20:E34,I20:I34").Cells
    tmp = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    If cell.Value = n And tmp Like "*#-#*" Then
       'get the first number
        num = CLng(Trim(Split(tmp, "-")(0)))
        'find the next empty cell in the appropriate row
        Set rngDest = sht.Cells(num, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)
        'make sure not to add before col L
        If rngDest.Column < 12 Then Set rngDest = sht.Cells(num, 12)
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Copy rngDest

' This is getting the next number in A/E/I----
        Set tmp = cell.Offset(1, 0)

' This is filling up B17 - F18 in order until filled
        If sht.Range("B17").Value = "" Then
            sht.Range("C17").Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            sht.Range("B17").Value = tmp.Value
        ElseIf sht.Range("B18").Value = "" Then
            sht.Range("C18").Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            sht.Range("B18").Value = tmp.Value
        ElseIf sht.Range("E17").Value = "" Then
            sht.Range("F17").Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            sht.Range("E17").Value = tmp.Value
        ElseIf sht.Range("E18").Value = "" Then
            sht.Range("F18").Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            sht.Range("E18").Value = tmp.Value
        End If
  '---- This clears the BCD/FGH/JKL columns after using the value ----
        'cell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(, 3).Value = ""


   End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Christofer
                                                                           Thanks so much for your help on this macro. I just tested the addition and this is what is happening:
- It seems that the macro is no longer using the entered number in cell A1. It copies everything into cells L1:L12
- The numbers in cells A20:A34,E20:E34,I20:I34 are not being copied they are being moved (only need the copy part).
                                                                                   So if could help on these two issues that would be great.

Comment: Oops, I botched a line. ' If n And tmp Like "*#-#*" Then' should be 'If cell.Value = n And tmp Like "*#-#*" Then' I'll update the code. That will fix it from not using A1 properly.
I'm not sure what you mean by "are not being copied they are being moved ". I'm not touching the values in column A,E and I. If you mean the values in "B,C,D"/"F,G,H"/"J,K,L", then I'm copying and deleting them. You said you wanted them blank?
If you don't want to remove the values, comment out the 'cell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(, 3).Value = ""' part.

Comment: Sorry, there is another error. I thought you specifically wanted the "A35" number when the entry was found in column A, and E35 when found in column E. This can be changed very easily, but what is supposed to happen if there is no number below?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't as clear as I should have been. For the range: A20:A34,E20:E34,I20:I34 the found number could be located in anyone of these cells and so always use the next cell down (their will always be a number). Please see the Excel sample sheet. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Ok, well, that's how it should work now, give it a try.

Comment: A couple issues are:If the found number was in E20 the cell E21 would be used as the number to be copied and posted. So the found number could be in any one or two cells in the cell range: A20:A34,E20:E34 and I20:I34 and the following cell would be used as the number to be placed in the appropriate cell B17, C17, E17, E18.The second issue is when it finds the number from cell A1 it should copy and paste only.
If you check the sample Excel sheet I posted it has 2 examples with the result. It may help to give a visual look.
Again, sorry for the hassle.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. If the first result is found in E20, the value of E21 is copied to B17. Wasn't that what you wanted? Because that's what i looks like...

Comment: In your question you say, and I quote; "After all the coping and pasting all the cells B34, C34 and D34 need to be deleted and so would be blank. Same for F20, G20 and H20." So what are you saying? You don't want to delete them? Then just comment out the last line that clears those as I said.

Comment: Hi, have an idea. If we look at the sample Excel sheet you’ll see cell A1 with an 8. In this example only,that is the search number for cells A20:A34,E20:E34,I20:I34. So found cell A34 and E20 (cell to the right B34, G20) are both copied to cell L8 and L1. Cell B34 is copied to cell C17 and F20 is copied to cell C18. Cell A35 is copied to B17 and cell E21 to B18. Cells B34,C34,D34 and F20, G20,H20 are then deleted. This would be done for any found number A1. The end. Right now the found number is being deleted and not copied.  Communicating can be difficult. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Correction: my line " Right now the found number is being deleted and not copied. should read  Right now the found number is being deleted.

Comment: Yes? And I told you... nevermind, I commented out that last line for you. Now it's not deleting anything. Better?

Comment: It works, it works! 
You’ve been very patient with me and I’m very grateful but I was wondering if I could ask another small favor. 
If I had just one range of cells, say A20:A35 that only has one row of numbers to the right of it (unlike the other cell ranges that have a total of 3 rows to the right of it) so only cells B20:B35 and no other rows what line of code what I use and where does it get placed?
As always thank-you very much.

Comment: I mean, technically, you should be able to use the exact same code. If you want to skip the other columns, you can change       For Each cell In sht.Range("A20:A34,E20:E34,I20:I34").Cells    to       For Each cell In sht.Range("A20:A34").Cells. The numbers in column "C" and "D" are never touched by the code, so if they wouldn't exist it wouldn't change anything. If that's what you mean.

Comment: I've been playing with the line"For Each cell In sht.Range("A20:A34").Cells' and it only does it's thing correctly with the change but I also would like to keep the other 2 rows but with the removal of other 2 cells. It's like I need anther 2 or more lines to do this. One line for cells A20:A34 and another for E20:E34,I20:I34. Thanks again.

Comment: It's no problem separating them, and making two For loops, or even having the loop doing different things for the different rows. I'm just not sure exactly what you want it to do differently.

Comment: Hi, i got it. i really appreciate all your help. Karen